# Jordan canonical form and rational canonical form for $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = A$.

Tags: jordan-normal-form

I am trying to solve the following problem using **both** Jordan canonical form and rational canonical form:

> let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices with entries in a field. Suppose that $A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$. Prove that there is an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQB = BQ^{-1}AQ$.

Here is my progress:
$A^2 = A \implies$ the minimal polynomial for $A$, $m_A(x)$ divides $x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ (the factorization works because every field contains a $-1$, am I right?) So $m_A(x) = x, x-1,$ or $x(x-1)$.

**Jordan canonical form approach:**

Because the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ have the same roots, the eigenvalues of $A$ can only be $0$ or $1$ or both, so they are all contained in this field. Therefore, the Jordan canonical form for $A$ exists. Because $m_A(x)$ has no repeated roots, its Jordan canonical form is actually a diagonal matrix. So there exists a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix. Similarly, we can find a matrix $R$ such that $R^{-1}BR$ is a diagonal matrix. Since diagonal matrices commute with one another, we have $(P^{-1}AP)(R^{-1}BR) = (R^{-1}BR)(P^{-1}AP)$, and rearrangement gives $Q^{-1}AQB = BQ^{-1}AQ$ where $Q = PR^{-1}$.

Can someone check if this approach is correct?

**Now the rational canonical form approach:**

Because $m_A(x) = x, x-1,$ or $x(x-1)$, the list of invariant factors is one of the following:

$x, x, \dots, x$

$x-1, x-1, \dots, x-1$

$x(x-1), x(x-1), \dots, x(x-1)$

$x, \dots, x, x(x-1) , \dots, x(x-1)$

$x-1, \dots, x-1, x(x-1), \dots, x(x-1)$

The degree of the product of the invariant factors for each list should equal to $n$.

The companion matrix for $x$ is $(0)$, for $x-1$ is $(1)$, and for $x(x-1)$ is \begin{pmatrix}
 0 &0\\
 1 &1
\end{pmatrix}. So I know the rational canonical forms for $A$ and $B$ are matrices with all entries to be $0$ except for possibly $1$'s on the diagonal and the subdiagonal. But how do I continue from here?

Comment: The argument with the JCF is correct. BUT. You don't need anything as deep as the JCF or RCF to show that $A^2=A$ implies $V=\ker A\oplus \text{im} A$ and that $A$ acts as the identity on $\text{im} A$. [This is completely elementary: "projections". ]. Then use the second half of your JCF argument. So imho it is perverse to try to do this with the RCF, unless you're wrting a book called Easy Mathematics made Difficult.